# Humphreys page 63 - error?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Looking at Humphreys linear algebraic groups, page 63.

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group. Let $K[G]$ be the associated algebra. Let $\varphi:G\times G\to G$ be right translation $\varphi(g,x)=\varphi_g(x)=xg$ and let $\varphi^*_x:K[G]\to K[G]$ be its comorphism: $\varphi^*_x:f\mapsto f\circ \varphi_x$.

Humphreys writes generators $f_1,\dots,f_n\in K[G]$ and lets $F$ be the vector space given by the span of these elements. He then uses two propositions to say that $F$ is stable under translations of functions, and to show that $\varphi^* F\subset K[G]\otimes_K F$.

He then goes on to say with this we have $\varphi^*_x f_i=\sum_{j=1}^n m_{ij}(x)f_j$. Although technically correct here, I think this labeling is morally wrong, and should read: $$\varphi_x^* f_j = \sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij}(x)f_i$$

The objective was to assign $\Psi:G\to \text{GL}(F)$ so that we have a faithful representation of $G$. So I want to have $g\mapsto (m_{ij}(g))$, where $(m_{ij}(g))$ is the matrix corresponding to $\varphi^*_g|_E$, with respect to the basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$. In this case I would like for  $(m_{ij}(g))f_k = \sum_j m_{jk}f_j$. (Which works with my labeling)

For his to work, it seems I would take $(f_k)(m_{ij}(g))=\sum_j m_{kj}f_j$? I.e. the matrix multiplies from the right? Is this perhaps his intention?

Comment: Without commenting on the specifics of this text, I will just say that it is not so unusual for matrices to multiply from the right. It means that the vectors become row vectors rather than column vectors. While this is the opposite to the convention that one usually learns in linear algebra, it does have the advantage that the product $AB$ means "do $A$, then $B$" which (imho) is less confusing than the reverse convention.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a representation $\Psi : G \to GL_d(F)$, that is, $\Psi(g) \Psi(h) = \Psi(gh)$ for all $g, h \in G$. Let us look at what happens when we use Humphrey's notation $\varphi^*_x f_i = \sum_{j} m_{i,j}(x) f_j $. Then you have
$$\begin{array}{rl}\sum_{k,j} m_{i,j}(g)m_{j,k}(h) f_k 
&= \sum_{j} m_{i,j}(g)  \varphi^*_h(f_j) \\ 
&= \varphi^*_h(\sum_{j} m_{i,j}(g) f_j) \\ 
&= \varphi^*_h(\varphi^*_g(f_i)) \\ 
&= \varphi^*_{gh}(f_i)  \\
&= \sum_{k} m_{i,k}(gh) f_k
\end{array} $$
And thus (Note that for this to work you have actually to take a basis of your finite dimensional vector space, not just a generating set) you obtain 
$$ m_{i,k}(gh) = \sum_{j} m_{i,j}(g) m_{j,k}(h) $$ which amounts to $\Psi(g) : = (m_{i,j}(g))$ having the desired property.

You might want to check for yourself that your convention $\varphi^*_x f_j = \sum_{j} m_{i,j}(x) f_i$ would lead to $\Psi(gh) = \Psi(h) \Psi(g)$ the other way around.

The main reason for this is that you have $\varphi^*_x \varphi^*_y = \varphi^*_{yx}$ and so your vector space becomes a *right* $G$-module and not a left one. Thus mulitplying from the right is more natural in this context.